# code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', path: 'D:\\tamrin angular\\react\\first-app\\node_modules\\react-refresh\\package.json', requestPath: 'react-refresh'

Tags: reactjs

ge.json has a valid "main" entry
at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:444:19)
at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:715:18)
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1130:27)
at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/helpers:187:19)
at Object. (D:\tamrin angular\react\first-app\node_modules@pmmmwh\react-refresh-webpack-plugin\lib\utils\injectRefreshLoader.js:16:47)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
path: 'D:\tamrin angular\react\first-app\node_modules\react-refresh\package.json',
requestPath: 'react-refresh'
}

npm install react-scripts@latest

My problem is completely solved